# Is this code legal in ISO C++?

Tags: c++, initialization, c++14, iso

So I'm trying to implement function parameters which can be uninitialized. Here is the code which I have written. My question is if it's legal by the ISO C++ standard (version 14 if possible).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

template<typename type>

struct nzeroinittmpliteral
{
    nzeroinittmpliteral() { }    
    nzeroinittmpliteral(type arg) { d = arg; }    
    //nzeroinittmpliteral(const nzeroinittmpliteral &) = delete;    
    operator type () & { return d; }   
    operator type () && { return d; }  
    type d;
} ;

void func(bool bIsPointerValid, nzeroinittmpliteral<int *> pVar = {})
{
    if(bIsPointerValid)
    {
        cout << *pVar << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        pVar = new int;    
        *pVar = 8;    
        cout << *pVar << endl;    
        delete pVar;
    }
}

int main()
{
    func(true, { (int *)&(const int &)int{9} } );    
    func(false);
}
```

Comment: note: `nzeroinittmpliteral<T>::operator*()` is not declared, thus this code doesn't compile.

Comment: Can you describe what you are actually trying to achieve here? There is probably a better way. If this is for "efficiency", then newing that int will be much slower than simply passing a dummy 0 or something.

Comment: `{ (int *)&(const int &)int{9} }` I don't know what this is supposed to be, but I'm pretty sure it's bad.

Comment: I'm just passing an address to temporary because I don't want to name one for the example.

Comment: @Guilherme Bernal - It's not but there is a suitable conversion defined to 'int *'.

Comment: Why pass an extra "is valid" boolean just so you can pass an uninitialized pointer via this monstrosity when you could just pass and check against `nullptr`? Besides, that parameter is not "uninitialized" at all, but defaulted (and zero-initialized).

Comment: Perhaps the example here is not that good as 'sizeof(bool)' is almost always equal 'sizeof(int*)' so there won't be any performance cost but imagine your data is bigger and that you'll need only a small part of it to indicate it's validity - then initialiazing it with some values when it's not used is worthless. The fact that we use the input parameter both as a local to store some data in certain cases and in other as a real input data saves us virtual memory.

Comment: I think it's left uninitialized - at least on 'Clang'.

Comment: The code seems legal to me (although not a very good idea if it's meant to be used the way it is)

Comment: `{ (int *)&(const int &)int{9} }` may be allowed by the standard, but certainly shouldn't be by any sane code reviewer.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to pass a parameter that may be uninitialized, simply don't pass it, use overloading. Look:

```
void func(int value)
{
    cout << value << endl;
}

void func()
{
    // no 'value' was initialized here :)
    func(8);
}
```

Or simply give a default value to the parameter if you will provide one anyway in your body:

```
void func(int value = 8)
{
    cout << value << endl;
}
```

Besides that, you can take a look at [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html):

```
void func(boost::optional<int> optvalue = boost::none) {
    if (optvalue) {
        cout << *optvalue << endl;
    } else {
        // nothing passed
        cout << "foo" << endl;
    }
}
```

---

Directly answering your question: your code is valid.

```
func(true, { (int *)&(const int &)int{9} } );
```

By casting the temporary to a const reference, you extend its lifetime to the lifetime of the reference itself, which ends after `func` returns. But this is too redundant, you could simply have written:

```
void func(int* value) { if (value) {...} }

func(&(const int &)9);
func(nullptr);
```

The actual parameter being passed is your `nzeroinittmpliteral` and it is initialized by calling one of the constructors, always. The default constructor doesn't initialize the `d` member, but this is no big improvement as it is just a pointer. Using `nullptr` is better and removes the need for the bool parameter.

Comment: `&(const int&)9` cannot convert to `int*` ... for good reason.  The OP's code is "valid", but only marginally -- it casts a pointer-to-temporary-int to pointer-to-non-const-int, which is legal *unless you modify the resulting pointer-to-int*.  Legal, but extremely dangerous.

Comment: At least for what he's actually doing, it could be even simpler than that. Could be just `void func(int x = 8) { cout << x << "\n"; } int main() { f(9); f();}`